# Quick Hull Worst case explanation

Tags: algorithm, recursion

What is the worst case for quick hull?? And how we can know that it is the worst case
I am confused with quick hull algorithm. Actually, I understood, that running determinant to find the area of a triangle, and if the area is positive, then the point is on the left of the extreme points.
And doing this thing recursively, will have O(n) efficiency for constructing a hull. 
Then I don't understood, that how to efficiency is sometimes mentioned O(nlogn) and )(n^2)? for which cases this efficiency turns out and how?
please if someone can help by some particular example; that would be great help.

Comment: when you searched the internet, what did you find? You did search, right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

QuickHull is a fast algorithm because in one of the steps you **eliminate a bunch of points** that lie inside a triangle. The steps for QuickHull are:

1. You choose the rightmost and leftmost points and trace a line between them
2. You find the point that is the farthest from your line
3. You draw a triangle between these three points
4. You eliminate points inside your triangle and go back to step 2.

This is the case when your points are placed randomly on the plane, but there are cases when the points are badly distributed and you can't eliminate any of them in any given step. One of this cases is when the points are in the border of a **circle**:

[image]

As you can see, when this happens, in step 4 of the algorithm above you eliminate no points at all. This is why in the worst case QuickHull is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is not correct. Please see my answer for a detailed description why.

Answer (score 32):

I'm afraid the accepted answer is **not** correct.

In fact, the case above is the *O(n log n)* case. Just look at the recursion tree. In each step you cut the set of points in two approximately equally large subsets. Therefore the height of the recursion tree is *O(log n)*, resulting in an overall runtime of *O(n log n)*.

To be more precise: The recurrence relation of the quickhull algorithm is *T(n) = T(a * n) + T(b * n) + c*n*. The last term (*c*n*) represents the search for the pivot element. In the case constructed above, the constants *a* and *b* are *a = b = 1/2*. You can use the master theorem to determine the bound of *O(n log n)*.

The worst case *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* is *a*n ≈ n-1* and *b*n ≈ 1*. You can construct it by placing points on the border of a circle using the following rule (in polar coordinates): *P<sub>i</sub> = (r, π / 2<sup>i</sup>)*. With this set of points the pivot element will always be the left-most point and therefore the set is divided into a subset containing n-1 points and an empty subset. So in each step of the recursion you only "eliminate" one point (the pivot element). The height of the recursion tree is therefore *O(n)* resulting in an overall efficiency of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an animated demo of [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457421/77567), demonstrating how at each step, only one point is removed from consideration:

[image: demo of]