# Limitations of threads and blocks and execution of threads and blocks

Tags: cuda

I have gone trough so few good reference guides, but still I am confused with limitations on threads and blocks.
1)Basic question: No. of blocks per grid in configuration execution, it means, grid will consume all SMs or single SM?

2)Actually it is told, as per compute capability, that you can have 8 block per SM, then
why sometimes they are telling, that you can configure 65535 blocks in each dimension?
I understood, 8 blocks will run in parallel but how one can configure 65535 blocks, how would they
execute? Will they be per SM or per grid?

3)Total no. of threads according to compute capability is 1024/block and 1536/SM,
then for 2D in each dimension how many max no. of threads can I have at same time and then if more i have configured then how many sequentially? The total should be within 1024?And i have checked practically, sometimes i am configuring threads more than its limitations per block, then also it is working, why is it so? 
3a)case a: for GT200, it is given that there are 30SMs, and each SM can have upto 8 blocks,
thus it concludes that there can be total 240 blocks(considering all SMs), then why it is 
sometimes mentioned that 65535 blocks can be configured in each dimension?
3b)case b:Also, in one of my program, my input size of matrix was 10,000 x 10,000 and I have done following configuration, 
-no. of blocks per grid: 1
-no. of threads per block: 10,000, 
It was still working, as no. of threads per block is exceeding the limitation still it is working.can anyone make me explain why it was working? And in which fashion threads and blocks are executed?
working,

Comment: Seriously - one question per question please. And do read some documentation, this is really clearly discussed in the CUDA programming guide.

Comment: @talonmies: Ok. I will put 1 question per question.

Comment: @robot, some advice:  First, this is at least the 3rd time you've been advised to put one question per question.  Saying "OK" and then not doing it will not get you any fans on SO. Second, I see that you've posted at least 4 answered questions and you haven't accepted any of the answers.  Some may look at that and decide it's not worth helping you.  I suggest you go back through the questions that have been answered, and accept some answers like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329345/quick-hull-worst-case-explanation), where you've already indicated that the answer helped you.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: Actually I'm new to SO, and due to that probably I'm not knowing how to work on it properly; but I realize and I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the grid associated with any kernel launch can use any or all of the SMs in a GPU.  This is handled by hardware scheduling logic on the GPU and you should not concern yourself with the details of it.   The GPU will attempt to best schedule your blocks on available SMs to maximize throughput.
2. The queue that feeds an SM can have blocks that are in various stages of readiness to run.  The 8 blocks per SM refers to the idea that the warp scheduler in the SM can choose warps out of any of those 8 blocks to execute at any time.  You can have more blocks queued up, but they will not have the possibility of actively running warps until some of the blocks ahead of them have been retired.  You can have more than 8 blocks per SM launched, of course.  These are simply queued up and waiting to run, as SMs become available (i.e. as the execution slots on SMs are freed up as blocks get retired.)  Once all SMs have up to 8 blocks in execution slots, then remaining blocks in the grid are waiting for these execution slots to free up.
3. The total number of threads per grid is not a well-defined number.  This is mostly a matter of hardware/resource limitations on-chip, not a specified or defined number.  Of course maximum threads per block is well-defined.  Certainly hundreds of millions of threads can be handled in a single grid launch, probably more.  But if you try to configure a grid that has 65535*65535 blocks (2D), each block having 1024 threads (in whatever arrangement), you're probably going to have a kernel launch failure.  But you can certainly get 65535 blocks in one dimension and a smaller number in the other (or other 2 dimensions, for a 3D grid).
4. (3a.)  Yes on GT200, there are 30 SMs.  If each SM can handle 8 blocks in a ready-to-execute queue, then that is 240 blocks.  But we can have many more blocks that are in another queue in the GPU, waiting to run.  They are waiting for execution slots to open up.  When a slot opens up, they come out of the waiting queue, and get assigned to a specific SM.  So a grid (all the blocks associated with a kernel launch) can have many more than 240 blocks in it.
5. (3b.) If you attempt to launch a kernel with a thread dimension of 10000 per block, it will fail.  I can't explain your case since you haven't provided an example, you've merely said "it works".  I'm sorry, it does **not** work.  Please provide a short, complete, compilable example that you think demonstrates it, and someone will show you the error.  For example, are you doing error checking when you launch a kernel this way?

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. 
1)But if I am configuring the kernel for GT200 as: kernelfunction<<<128,32>>>, (128 blocks & 32 threads),then it will produce 4096 threads. Then the no. of threads per SM will not be exceeded by its limitation?
2)If i'm configuring as: dimGrid(128,1,1) and dimBlock(32,32,1)then we are using 1024 threads per block,also total threads per SM can be 1024, it means i can take 1024/1024=1 block at maximum/SM. is it right. i know this is not good configuration but will it work; and what if i change to dimBlock(64,64,1). will it work?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yes, actually I'm trying to figure out the concepts regarding boundary conditions.
You answers helped me a lot about understanding so many concepts of GPU.

Comment: You mentioned in your point 3, that if I'm configuring 65535*65535 blocks(2D) with 1024 threads, then there will be kernel launch failure. If you can please explain me, why this kernel launch failure?

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you. My sense is simply that it's too many threads and the GPU may run out of resources.  But I can't point you to a specification that would be violated.  It may work -- you can try it and see what happens.  My experience has been that eventually if you make a grid large enough in terms of number of threads, it stops working (unspecified kernel launch failure).  My experience is you run into this problem before you hit the maximum theoretical grid size of 65535x65535x65535 blocks x 1024threads/block.